# pasar consulta de vencimiento a laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, carbon

Tengo un problema en pasar una consulta mysql a laravel
resulta que tengo una tabla producto con un campo 'vencimiento'
y para que me muestre los productos próximos a vencer hago esta consulta en mysql

```py
SELECT * FROM productos
where vencimiento between curdate() and date_add(curdate(), interval 30 day)
```

y bueno me muestra los productos proximos a vencer en los 30 dias.
pero no se como pasar esta consulta a laravel,, que sad..

```py
$productos=Productos::where('vencimiento')->between('curdate',)->interval(30 day);
```

pero no sabria como integrar el curdate y si esta bieen como voy .
porfavor alguien podria ayudarme :( les agradesco si me brindan almenos una ayudita.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desde Laravel 5.5.x no es necesario incluir el namespace de Carbon, ni mucho menos llamar a la clase para traer el timestamp de la hora actual, tan solo es necesario usar el helper `now()` y este va a traer una instancia de Carbon:

```
$fecha1 = now()->toDateString();

$fecha2 = now()->addDays(30)->toDateString();

$data = Productos::whereBetween('vencimiento', [$fecha1, $fecha2])->get();
```

Enlace a la documentación respectiva: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-now

Comment: Si tambien Funciona, Gracias :D

Answer (score 2):

Usando **Carbon** que se utiliza para trabajar con fechas dentro de Laravel y que ya viene incluida en el framework, pudieras intentarlo de este modo:

Previo a lo que te explicaré, debes importar el `namespace` de la clase *Carbon* al inicio de tu controlador de este modo:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

Paso 1.

Obtenemos la fecha actual y la formateamos para solo obtener año-mes-dí

```
$fechaInicio = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
```

Paso 2.

Obtenemos la fecha reciente mas 30 días según lo que veo en tu propia consulta

```
$fechaFin = Carbon::now()->addDays(30)->toDateString();
```

- Obtenemos la fecha actual
- Le agregamos por medio del método `addDays(30)` 30 días a la fecha actual
- Finalmente en otra fecha formateamos la fecha aumentada para solo obtener año-mes-día

Finalmente podemos usar el método `whereBetween()` para buscar entre fechas en Eloquent, de este modo:

```
$data = Productos::whereBetween('vencimiento', [$fechaInicio, $fechaFin])->get();
```

**Enlaces de interés**

- [`addDays()`](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub)
- [`toDateString()`](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting)
- [`whereBetween`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses)

Comment: Eres El Éxito, me hubiera pasado horas y oras y ras haciendome viejo y no iba a llegar a esta solución, te agradesco  muchisimo,sabes que se me ha caido una lagrima.